# how to read remote file protected by username and password in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails 3 application. One of the function is to get/read a remote file through a URL, and before getting there, I need to provide username and password to access.

The following link is an example:

https://demo.pshealth.co.uk/suite/logs/login-audit.csv.2011-01-27

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html) for that.